# Why am I getting these errors after running sudo apt-get -f install?

Tags: software-center, uninstall

```
sudarshan@sudarshan-DL-H61MXP:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libreoffice-common
Suggested packages:
  libreoffice-style-crystal libreoffice-style-hicontrast
  libreoffice-style-human libreoffice-style-oxygen libreoffice-style-tango
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libreoffice-common
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 22 not upgraded.
10 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/11.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 65.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 276873 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libreoffice-common (from .../libreoffice-common_1%3a4.0.2-0ubuntu1_all.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a4.0.2-0ubuntu1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/soffice', which is also in package openoffice.org-debian-menus 3.4-9593
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/var/lib/libreoffice/share/prereg/’: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/var/lib/libreoffice/share/’: Directory not empty
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/var/lib/libreoffice/program/’: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/var/lib/libreoffice’: Directory not empty
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/var/lib/libreoffice’: Directory not empty
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...
Processing triggers for gnome-icon-theme ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info ...
Unknown media type in type 'all/all'
Unknown media type in type 'all/allfiles'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mms'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmst'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmsu'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/pnm'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspt'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspu'
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
  /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a4.0.2-0ubuntu1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the error message, you have a conflict with `openoffice.org-debian-menus`. Maybe you can try to remove it and install libreoffice again